# Extjs invisible scroll for one single grid

Tags: extjs, scrollbar

I use extjs 4.2.1 and I have a grid with horizontal scrollbar.
And I need the grid to be scrollable, but scrollbar invisible.

The question is, is there any specific styles for scrolling in extjs so I could use and set height for scrollbar 0, for example.

I already saw solutions with padding and positioning, like
[Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)
stackoverflow.com/questions/25095539/allow-scroll-but-hide-scrollbar

but this doesn't suit me, cause my grid has lockable part (which doesn't have scroll) and not lockable part (which has horizontal scrolling that i want to hide). So these css tricks are not working.

Will appreciate any advice, thanks

Comment: If I were you, I'd have a look at how they implemented it for the locked part. Because the locked part is scrollable, but has no own (visible) scrollbar...

Comment: hmm.. but it's not scrollable. why do you think it is? it's scrollable only when i add overflow-x: scroll, the scrollbar is not hidden. i don't think that they did some specific logic for it to hide it, cause it's not hidden

Comment: Well, I have only tested against 6.0.1 that the locked part is scrolling when I use the mousewheel. Not sure about 4.2.1, they brought three bugfix releases for that version alon (4.2.4 is the most recent I think).